# IFile to IResource

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How can I get an IResource from an IFile or from an absolute path?

I tried with:

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();
resource = root.findMember(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

But I get a `null` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IFile` extends `IResource` so if you have an `IFile` you have an `IResource`.

`findMember` treats the path it is given as relative to the container (the workspace root in this case). So you can't use it to find a file given an absolute file path - you must use the `findFilesForLocation` APIs for that.

Answer (score 2):

[`IFile` extend `IResource`](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IFile.html), or with other words an `IFile` is an `IResource`.